# Undefined control sequence error in a table, cannot solve it, any help?

Tags: tables, undefined

Latex compile my code (I use overleaf) which looks ok but I am getting error message that the head is not defined and I need to use "\hbox" (not sure what it is) for the following code I used-

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Mechanism of abc}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{14cm}}
\toprule [1.5pt]
\hline{Mechanism of abc}\\
 \midrule
1. CTT \\ 
2. DTT\\ 
3. MATTTT \\
\bottomrule [1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: `\midrule`, `\head`, `\bottomrule` are not defined by default, you presumably used `booktabs` package to define the rules, any example that you saw using `\head` must have defined that (often it is just defined as a shorthand in the document)  (unrelated but never use `\\ ` after `\end{table}`)

Comment: The error message informs you that the command `\head` that you used in your code is not defined. You either forgot to load a package that defines it or forgot to define it yourself. Where did you learn about the `\head` command? Alternatively: do you like the output you get, if you replace `\head{Mechanism of ABC activation}\\ ` with `Mechanism of ABC activation\\ `?

Comment: That's absolutely right! thanks a lot, I indeed forgot to load booktabs package, I was following a manual book and learnt about the \head command. For the table title column, can I use "\hline{Mechanism of ABC activation}\\" instead? It also works fine,but I do not like the format (not centered, not highlighted or anything), I would like atleast the title column to be bold, but not sure if i can have two commands before the "mechanism...." like \hline\fontbf?

Comment: @TomalikaUllah: `\hline` draws a horizontal line, so `\hline{text}` is not the correct use of the `\hline` command. If you want the column header to be bold, you can use `textbf{Mechanism of ABC activation}`.

Comment: `\hline` is completely different, and draws a rule It does not take an argument so just `\hline` not `\hline{...}`  you probably want `\newcommand\head[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{#1}}}` to make a bold centred heading, but whatever tutorial you saw using this non standard command would have defined it. We can only guess what defintion  your tutorial was using.

Comment: None of these help, I get more errors. For a single column table, for the title row, is there any other way to make the centered/bold text? I thought \centering would automatically centre every line?

Comment: as already mentioned, please provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. here there is no document class or preamble

Comment: I edited my question with the minimal example commands that I used, is that what you meant? My apologies as I am fairly new to TEX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you after the following:

[image]

The MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document, which compilation generate table showed above, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Mechanism of abc}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth}}
    \toprule [1.5pt]
\thead{Mechanism of abc}\\
    \midrule
1. CTT \\
2. DTT\\
3. MATTTT \\
    \bottomrule [1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

From comparison with your code fragment you can observe:

- In document preamble are loaded two packages: `booktabs` (for defined table rules `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomerule` used in your table and `makecell` (which among other define `thead` macro.
- Instead to use `\head`, which you latter rename to `\hline` is used `\thead, which is defined in the` \makecell` caption
- Instead `p{14cm}` is used `p{\textwidth}`. By this table is not wide than text in your document.

Hopefully, above MWE can serve as starting point in design of your table(s).

To make yourself more familiar with LaTeX I advice you to read some introductory texts like [No so short Introduction to LaTeX2e](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), or for tables [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) etc. On web you can find (by googling) many examples, also all packages for support at writing tables are accompanied with instruction how to use them.